# Differences Equations and Theory of Numbers

Tags: number-theory, contest-math

The positive integers $a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_{3030}$ satisfy
$$
2a_{n+2} = a_{n+1}+4a_n
$$
for all $n = 0, 1, 2, ..., 3028$.

Prove that at least one of the elements $a_0, a_1, a_2, ..., a_{3030}$ is divisible by $2^{2020}$.

My kid gave me this problem and we can´t do it. Someone could me help? I was thinking about principle of the Pigeon Houses, but without success.

Comment: I think the resemblance to the pigeonhole principle is likely a false lead.  Instead consider what is required for $a_{n+2}$ to be a "positive integer".

Comment: @hardmath I think that to be $a_{n+2}$ positive integer we have to $a_{n+1}+4a_n>0$ and that $a_{n + 1}$ must be an even number.

Comment: Okay, take it one step further (actually, backward).  For $a_{n+1}$ to be an even integer, what is required for $a_n$?

Comment: Thanks @hardmath. I got it. Thanks too much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We prove by induction, assume that the statement is true for any $k\leq N$ sequence $a_0,...,a_{3k}$ satisfy
$$2a_{n+2}=a_{n+1}+4a_n$$
We will prove for case $k=N+1$.

For all $n=0,...,3N$ we have
$$a_{n+1}=2a_{n+2}-4a_n=2(2a_{n+3}-4a_{n+1})-4a_n=4(a_{n+3}-2a_{n+1}-a_n)$$
So $4 \mid a_n$ for all $n=1,...,3N+1$. The sequence $\dfrac{a_1}{4},...,\dfrac{a_{3N+1}}{4}$ satisfy the recursive condition so by assumption, there exists an element which is divisible by $4^N$. Thus, there must be an element $a_n$ which is divisible by $4^{N+1}$.

I miss the part that clearly the statement is true for $N=1$ since $4 \mid a_1$ from same computation as above.